# Choosing IBM DB for the chatbots data

Tags: database, ibm-cloud, chatbot, ibm-watson, watson-conversation

I am creating the chatbot, through which I am trying to collect set of data from the user by asking questions. I have to store those data into DB and then, I should display it back in the front-end. I am using elastic search by using reactivesearch in my react app through which searching functions happens at the client side. I am bit perplexed, which DB I should choose. I have worked on NoSQL DB like mongoDB, DynamoDB before. Which NoSQL DB would be more useful to store chatbot data and for easy integration with react application?

Answer (score 2):

I honestly don't think it really matters. You're just storing and fetching the data, so whatever is easiest for you to work with and faster on the response time side.

It sounds like you have a handle on the pattern so the database type doesn't really matter imo because its such a simple interaction.

Comment: Thanks, I will pick the best option available.